# I want to get the name of the items of the component from an array which is as shown in screenshot

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I want to get name of the item of my components in tabsConfig. I am able to get item.name but now want to dig inside the nested array and find out basically 'item.components.item.name'. How can I do that? I am adding screenshot of object I am talking about for reference. And adding snippet of code where I want to get this name.

```
<TopTab.Navigator
          tabBarOptions={{
            scrollEnabled: true,
          }}>
          {dashboardsData.dashboardConfig.tabsConfig.map((item) => {
            console.log(dashboardsData);
            return (
              <TopTab.Screen
                key={JSON.stringify(item.name)}
                name={JSON.stringify(item.name)}
                component={TabDashboardDetail}
                initialParams={{
                  chartName: item.name,
                }}
              />
            );
          })}
        </TopTab.Navigator>
```

Here I want to get the chartName from object.

Here is TabDashboardDetail.js

```
  const title = route.params.chartName;
  return (
    <DefaultScrollView>
      <ChartView title={title}>
        <CogniAreaChart areaChartData={areaChartData} height={200} />
      </ChartView>
    </DefaultScrollView>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `map` function again for each object inside `item.components`.

```
{dashboardsData.dashboardConfig.tabsConfig.map((item) => {
    return (
        <>
            {/* example */}
            <ul>
                {item.components.map(component => {
                    <li>{component.name}</li>
                })}
            </ul>
        </>
    );
})}
```

Comment: Danoram thanks for reply, but I am getting problem in using map function inside TopTab.Screen in above question.

Comment: Try passing `item.components` to the `TabDashboardDetail` component as a prop if that is possible and map it inside there.

Comment: Danoram edited question with TabDashboardDetail.js